# Regex select all text between tags

Tags: html, regex, html-parsing

What is the best way to select all the text between 2 tags - ex: the text between all the  '`<pre>`' tags on the page.

Comment: Best way is to use a html-parser like "Beautiful Soup" if you're into python...

Comment: The best way is to use XML/HTML parser.

Comment: In general, using regular expressions to parse html is not a good idea:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Do not parse text between tags with regex because arbitrarily nested tags make HTML non-regular.  Matching tags seems to be okay.

`/<div>.*?<\/div>/.exec("<div><div></div></div>")`

Comment: <div\s+id="HEADER">(.|\n)*?<\/div>$

Answer (score 210, accepted):

You can use `"<pre>(.*?)</pre>"`, (replacing pre with whatever text you want) and extract the first group (for more specific instructions specify a language) but this assumes the simplistic notion that you have very simple and valid HTML.

As other commenters have suggested, if you're doing something complex, use a HTML parser.

Comment: This does not select the text _between_ the tags, it includes the tags.

Comment: You need to grab the selection using ()

Comment: For multi line tags: <html_tag>(.+)((\s)+(.+))+<\/html_tag>

Comment: This still has visibility so: If you're still seeing `<pre>` tags after trying `<pre>(.*?)<\/pre>`, it's because you're looking at what's captured by the Full match instead of the (.*?) capture group. Sounds cheesy but I always think "parenthesis = pair of thieves" because unless the `(` is followed by a `?` as in `(?:` or `(?>`, every match will have two captures: 1 for the full match & 1 for the capture group.  Each additional set of parenthesis adds a additional capture. You just have to know how to retrieve both captures in whatever language you're working with.

Comment: you need to escape /

Comment: An if tag has attributes?

Comment: What does the question mark do here?

Comment: This works flawlessly. if you have an id or class in those tag just:
<pre(.*?)<\/pre>

Answer (score 197):

Tag can be completed in another line. This is why `\n` needs to be added.

```
<PRE>(.|\n)*?<\/PRE>
```

Comment: Important point about adding `(.|\n)*?` when dealing with HTML tags across multiple lines. The selected answer works only if the HTML tags are on the same line.

Comment: <PRE>(.|\n|\r\n)*?<\/PRE> for Windows line endings

Comment: Never use `(.|\n)*?` to match any char. Always use `.` with `s` (singleline) modifier. Or a `[\s\S]*?` workaround.

Comment: I wanted to select code comments in notepad++, so using this answer I came up with `/\*(.|\n)*?\*/` which did the job -- thank you

Answer (score 52):

To exclude the delimiting tags:

```
(?<=<pre>)(.*?)(?=</pre>)
```

`(?<=<pre>)` looks for text after `<pre>`

`(?=</pre>)` looks for text before `</pre>`

Results will text inside `pre` tag

Comment: People using this look at @krishna thakor's answer which can also consider if the content has new line between tags

Comment: This helped in my case (not needing to consider newlines). Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work if you have multiple elements.  E.g., `<pre>first</pre><pre>second</pre>`

Comment: @EvanKleiner I checked it [here](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/c43bd8143a25) and it's working fine.

Answer (score 42):

## This is what I would use.

```
(?<=(<pre>))(\w|\d|\n|[().,\-:;@#$%^&*\[\]"'+–/\/®°⁰!?{}|`~]| )+?(?=(</pre>))
```

**Basically what it does is:**

`(?<=(<pre>))` Selection have to be prepend with `<pre>` tag

`(\w|\d|\n|[().,\-:;@#$%^&*\[\]"'+–/\/®°⁰!?{}|~]| )` This is just a regular expression I want to apply. In this case, it selects letter or digit or newline character or some special characters listed in the example in the square brackets. The pipe character `|` simply means "**OR**".

`+?` Plus character states to select one or more of the above - order does not matter. **Question mark** changes the default behavior from 'greedy' to 'ungreedy'.

`(?=(</pre>))` Selection have to be appended by the `</pre>` tag

[image]

Depending on your use case you might need to add some modifiers like (**i** or **m**)

- **i** - case-insensitive
- **m** - multi-line search

Here I performed this search in Sublime Text so I did not have to use modifiers in my regex.

## Javascript does not support lookbehind

The above example should work fine with languages such as PHP, Perl, Java ...
Javascript however does not support lookbehind so we have to forget about using `(?))` and look for some kind of workaround. Perhaps simple strip the first four chars from our result for each selection like in here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592033/regex-match-text-between-tags

Also look at the [JAVASCRIPT REGEX DOCUMENTATION](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) for **non-capturing parentheses**

Comment: Note that you need to escape the single/double quote characters with ` in order to put the regexp in a string.

Answer (score 26):

This answer supposes support for look around! This allowed me to identify all the text between pairs of opening and closing tags. That is all the text between the '>' and the '<'. It works because look around doesn't consume the characters it matches.

```regex
(?<=>)([\w\s]+)(?=<\/)
```

I tested it in https://regex101.com/ using this HTML fragment.

```html
<table>
<tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td><td>Cell 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Cell 4</td><td>Cell 5</td><td>Cell 6</td></tr>
</table>
```

It's a game of three parts: the look behind, the content, and the look ahead.

```
(?<=>)    # look behind (but don't consume/capture) for a '>'
([\w\s]+) # capture/consume any combination of alpha/numeric/whitespace
(?=<\/)   # look ahead  (but don't consume/capture) for a '</'
```

[image: screen capture from regex101.com]

I hope that serves as a started for 10. Luck.

Comment: Thank you. Not only this is a better answer, but also a great link to the regex101 site. Upvoted! 

Comment: The above regex is excellent as is, but it will only return the first match found and won't cover special chars nor new lines. For that, use the following instead: `myString.match(/(?<=>)([\w\s\-\!@#$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'?,.\/]+)(?=<\/)/gm);`. This will return an array with all the matches, including almost all special characters available.

Comment: @RaphaelSetin Instead of having a big regex combination for words and special characters we can have (?<=>)([^>]*)(?=<\/) ., This will match all the words, space and special character inside the text

Comment: @Vijayakumar I am not an expert with RegEx, that's why my proposed solution wasn't that fancy haha. If your solution works, that's even better. But the caveat in my opinion is that I don't know what special characters exactly yours covers. You should mention them at least.

Answer (score 25):

use the below pattern to get content between element. Replace `[tag]` with the actual element you wish to extract the content from.

```
<[tag]>(.+?)</[tag]>
```

Sometime tags will have attributes, like `anchor` tag having `href`, then use the below pattern.

```
 <[tag][^>]*>(.+?)</[tag]>
```

Comment: Try first example as  '<head>(.+?)</head>'  and works like expected. But I have no results with second one.

Comment: this doesn't work. `<[tag]>` will match `<t>`, `<a>` and `<g>`

Comment: @MA-Maddin - I think you missed the `Replace [tag] with the actual element you wish to extract the content from` part.

Comment: Oh well, yes. These `[]` should have been omitted altogether. That would be more clear, because of their meaning in RegEx and the fact, that people scan the code first and read the text after ;)

Answer (score 12):

This seems to be the simplest regular expression of all that I found

```
(?:<TAG>)([\s\S]*)(?:<\/TAG>)
```

1. Exclude opening tag `(?:<TAG>)` from the matches
2. Include any whitespace or non-whitespace characters `([\s\S]*)` in the matches
3. Exclude closing tag `(?:<\/TAG>)` from the matches

Comment: Thank you. I burned through all of the above before this one worked for me. Needed one to scrape SCSS in and HTML file -- innerHTML of `style[lang="scss"]` -- and this did the trick. Here it is: https://regex101.com/r/VqhNsI/1.

Comment: only one that worked for me (javascript)

Comment: it fails when the pre tag have the style attribute, check this [regex demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/71a4a2a6d3c7).

Comment: @AmineKOUIS try `(?:<pre[^>]*>)([\s\S]*)(?:<\/pre>)`

Answer (score 9):

You shouldn't be trying to parse html with regexes see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) and how it turned out.

In the simplest terms, html is not a regular language so you can't fully parse is with regular expressions.

Having said that you can parse subsets of html when there are no similar tags nested. So as long as anything between  and  is not that tag itself, this will work:

```
preg_match("/<([\w]+)[^>]*>(.*?)<\/\1>/", $subject, $matches);
$matches = array ( [0] => full matched string [1] => tag name [2] => tag content )
```

A better idea is to use a parser, like the native DOMDocument, to load your html, then select your tag and get the inner html which might look something like this:

```
$obj = new DOMDocument();
$obj -> load($html);
$obj -> getElementByTagName('el');
$value = $obj -> nodeValue();
```

And since this is a proper parser it will be able to handle nesting tags etc.

Comment: Just want to say I'm a slight bit disturbed that this is still gathering downvotes while it is the only answer which supplies a proper solution next to the regex one and I also added ample warning that it is probably not the right way... At least comment on what is so wrong about my answer, please.

Comment: The question was not tagged with `php`. Not sure how PHP came into the picture...

Comment: @trincot This was more than 7 years ago, so I cannot remember. In any case it is an example of solving the problem with a regex and with a parser. The regex is good and php is just what I knew well at the time.

Comment: I understand, I saw your first comment and thought that this could explain some of the downvotes.

Comment: "/<([\w]+)[^>]*>(.*?)<\/\1>/" in python not match

Answer (score 5):

Try this....

```
(?<=\<any_tag\>)(\s*.*\s*)(?=\<\/any_tag\>)
```

Comment: Note that look behind is not supported in JavaScript.

Comment: Ooo of course, but this regex is for Java. thanks for your note.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var str = "Lorem ipsum <pre>text 1</pre> Lorem ipsum <pre>text 2</pre>";
    str.replace(/<pre>(.*?)<\/pre>/g, function(match, g1) { console.log(g1); });
```

Since accepted answer is without javascript code, so adding that:

Answer (score 2):

`preg_match_all(/<pre>([^>]*?)<\/pre>/,$content,$matches)` this regex will select everyting between  tag. no matter is it in new line(work with multiline.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, setting the `DOTALL` flag will capture everything, including newlines.

> If the DOTALL flag has been specified, this matches any character including a newline. [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html)

```
#example.py using Python 3.7.4  
import re

str="""Everything is awesome! <pre>Hello,
World!
    </pre>
"""

# Normally (.*) will not capture newlines, but here re.DOTATLL is set 
pattern = re.compile(r"<pre>(.*)</pre>",re.DOTALL)
matches = pattern.search(str)

print(matches.group(1))
```

`python example.py`

```
Hello,
World!
```

## Capturing text between all opening and closing tags in a document

To capture text between all opening and closing tags in a document, `finditer` is useful. In the example below, three opening and closing `<pre>` tags are present in the string.

```
#example2.py using Python 3.7.4
import re

# str contains three <pre>...</pre> tags
str = """In two different ex-
periments, the authors had subjects chat and solve the <pre>Desert Survival Problem</pre> with a
humorous or non-humorous computer. In both experiments the computer made pre-
programmed comments, but in study 1 subjects were led to believe they were interact-
ing with another person. In the <pre>humor conditions</pre> subjects received a number of funny
comments, for instance: “The mirror is probably too small to be used as a signaling
device to alert rescue teams to your location. Rank it lower. (On the other hand, it
offers <pre>endless opportunity for self-reflection</pre>)”."""

# Normally (.*) will not capture newlines, but here re.DOTATLL is set
# The question mark in (.*?) indicates non greedy matching.
pattern = re.compile(r"<pre>(.*?)</pre>",re.DOTALL)

matches = pattern.finditer(str)


for i,match in enumerate(matches):
    print(f"tag {i}: ",match.group(1))
```

`python example2.py`

```
tag 0:  Desert Survival Problem
tag 1:  humor conditions
tag 2:  endless opportunity for self-reflection
```

Comment: very good Python code, thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
(?<=>)[^<]+
```

for Notepad++

```
>([^<]+)
```

for AutoIt (option *Return array of global matches*).

or

```
 (?=>([^<]+))
```

https://regex101.com/r/VtmEmY/1

Answer (score 1):

To select all text between pre tag I prefer

`preg_match('#<pre>([\w\W\s]*)</pre>#',$str,$matches);`

> $matches[0] will have results including <pre> tag

> $matches[1] will have all the content inside <pre>.

DomDocument cannot work in situations where the requirement is to get text with tag details within the searched tag as it strips all tags, nodeValue & textContent will only return text without tags & attributes.

Answer (score 1):

```
 test.match(/<pre>(.*?)<\/pre>/g)?.map((a) => a.replace(/<pre>|<\/pre>/g, ""))
```

this should be a preferred solution.especially if you have multiple pre tags in the context

Answer (score 1):

More complex than [PyKing's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7167486/4267880) but matches any type of tag (except self-closing) and considers cases where the tag has HTML-like string attributes.

`/<TAG_NAME(?:STRING|NOT_CLOSING_TAG_NOT_QUOTE)+>INNER_HTML<\/\1 *>/g`

Raw: `/<([^\s</>]+)(?:("(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*")|[^>"])+>(.*?)<\/\1 *>/g`

[Regex Railroad diagram](https://regexper.com/#%3C%28%5B%5E%5Cs%3C%2F%3E%5D%2B%29%28%3F%3A%28%22%28%3F%3A%5B%5E%22%5C%5C%5D%7C%5C%5C.%29*%22%29%7C%5B%5E%3E%22%5D%29%2B%3E%28.*%3F%29%3C%5C%2F%5C1%20*%3E):

group #1 = tag name

group #2 = string attr

group #3 = inner html

[image: Regex Railroad diagram]

JavaScript code testing it:

```js
let TAG_NAME = '([^\s</>]+)';
let NOT_CLOSING_TAG_NOT_QUOTE = '[^>"]';
let STRING = '("(?:[^"\\\\]|\\\\.)*")';

let NON_SELF_CLOSING_HTML_TAG =
                                                              // \1 is a back reference to TAG_NAME
    `<${TAG_NAME}(?:${STRING}|${NOT_CLOSING_TAG_NOT_QUOTE})+>(.*?)</\\1 *>`;

let tagRegex = new RegExp(NON_SELF_CLOSING_HTML_TAG, 'g');

let myStr = `Aenean <abc href="/life<><>\\"<?/abc></abc>"><a>life</a></abc> sed consectetur.
<a href="/work">Work Inner HTML</a> quis risus eget <a href="/about">about inner html</a> leo.
interacted with any of the <<<ve text="<></ve>>">abc</ve>`;

let matches = myStr.match(tagRegex);

// Removing 'g' flag to match each tag part in the for loop
tagRegex = new RegExp(NON_SELF_CLOSING_HTML_TAG);

for (let i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
  let tagParts = matches[i].match(tagRegex);
  console.log(`Tag #${i} = [${tagParts[0]}]`);
  console.log(`Tag #${i} name: [${tagParts[1]}]`);
  console.log(`Tag #${i} string attr: [${tagParts[2]}]`);
  console.log(`Tag #${i} inner html: [${tagParts[3]}]`);
  console.log('');
}
```

Output:

```
Tag #0 = [<abc href="/life<><>\"<?/abc></abc>"><a>life</a></abc>]
Tag #0 name: [abc]
Tag #0 string attr: ["/life<><>\"<?/abc></abc>"]
Tag #0 inner html: [<a>life</a>]

Tag #1 = [<a href="/work">Work Inner HTML</a>]
Tag #1 name: [a]
Tag #1 string attr: ["/work"]
Tag #1 inner html: [Work Inner HTML]

Tag #2 = [<a href="/about">about inner html</a>]
Tag #2 name: [a]
Tag #2 string attr: ["/about"]
Tag #2 inner html: [about inner html]

Tag #3 = [<ve text="<></ve>>">abc</ve>]
Tag #3 name: [ve]
Tag #3 string attr: ["<></ve>>"]
Tag #3 inner html: [abc]
```

This doesn't work if:

- The tag has any descendant tag of the same type
- The tag start in one line and ends in another. (In my case I
  remove line breaks from HTML)

If you change `(.*?)<\/\1 *>` to `([\s\S]*?)<\/\1 *>` it should match the tag's inner html even if everything is not in the same line. For some reason it didn't work for me on Chrome and Node but worked here with the JavaScript's Regex Engine:

https://www.regextester.com

Regex: `<([^\s</>]+)(?:("(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*")|[^>"])+>([\s\S]*?)<\/\1 *>`

Test String:

```
Aenean lacinia <abc href="/life<><><?/a></a>">  
<a>life</a></abc> sed consectetur.
<a href="/work">Work</a> quis risus eget urna mollis ornare <a href="/about">about</a> leo.
interacted with any of the <<<ve text="<></ve>>">abc</ve>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "[^<'tagname'/>]" );`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const content = '<p class="title responsive">ABC</p>';
const blog = {content};
const re = /<([^> ]+)([^>]*)>([^<]+)(<\/\1>)/;
const matches = content.match(re);
console.log(matches[3]);
```

`matches[3]` is the content text and this is adapted to any tag name with classes. (not support nested structures)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<PRE>(\X*?)<\/PRE>
```

Answer (score -1):

For multiple lines:

```
<htmltag>(.+)((\s)+(.+))+</htmltag>
```

Answer (score -1):

I use this solution:

```
preg_match_all( '/<((?!<)(.|\n))*?\>/si',  $content, $new);
var_dump($new);
```

Answer (score -1):

In Javascript (among others), this is simple.  It covers attributes and multiple lines:

```js
/<pre[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/pre>/
```

Answer (score -4):

```
<pre>([\r\n\s]*(?!<\w+.*[\/]*>).*[\r\n\s]*|\s*[\r\n\s]*)<code\s+(?:class="(\w+|\w+\s*.+)")>(((?!<\/code>)[\s\S])*)<\/code>[\r\n\s]*((?!<\w+.*[\/]*>).*|\s*)[\r\n\s]*<\/pre>
```

Comment: Please introduce / explain your answer using words.