# Regex match text between tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string:

```
My name is <b>Bob</b>, I'm <b>20</b> years old, I like <b>programming</b>.
```

I'd like to get the text between `b` tags to an array, that is:

```
['Bob', '20', 'programming']
```

I tried this `/<b>(.*?)<\/b>/.exec(str)` but it will only get the first text.

Comment: Use the DOM interface. Easier.

Comment: @EdHeal This html string is not in the DOM

Comment: Everything you ever needed to know about parsing HTML with a regular expression: [*RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Answer (score 155, accepted):

```
/<b>(.*?)<\/b>/g
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Add `g` (*global*) flag after:

```
/<b>(.*?)<\/b>/g.exec(str)
             //^-----here it is
```

However if you want to get all matched elements, then you need something like this:

```
var str = "<b>Bob</b>, I'm <b>20</b> years old, I like <b>programming</b>.";

var result = str.match(/<b>(.*?)<\/b>/g).map(function(val){
   return val.replace(/<\/?b>/g,'');
});
//result -> ["Bob", "20", "programming"]
```

If an element has attributes, regexp will be:

```
/<b [^>]+>(.*?)<\/b>/g.exec(str)
```

Comment: but the result is `["<b>Bob</b>", "Bob"]`?

Comment: _exec_ should be used multiple times, since it remember the last call result and return the next one.

Comment: @wong2 the tags are removed by the replace()

Comment: What if I need this to work for tags with attributes too?

Answer (score 15):

```
var root = document.createElement("div");

root.innerHTML = "My name is <b>Bob</b>, I'm <b>20</b> years old, I like <b>programming</b>.";

var texts = [].map.call( root.querySelectorAll("b"), function(v){
    return v.textContent || v.innerText || "";
});

//["Bob", "20", "programming"]
```

Answer (score 13):

Use *match* instead, and the g flag.

```
str.match(/<b>(.*?)<\/b>/g);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to always work, for example: https://jsfiddle.net/jnvey51L/2/

Comment: @Costantin this is because `.` does not match newlines by default. You can replace that dot by `[\s\S]` and things should work as you expect.  
Note that while this works for simple cases, this is not a perfect solution (for example nested tags will not work properly). RegExp are usually not recommended for HTML parsing. If you expect arbitrary strings, try using a [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString) and use things like `querySelectorAll` on the result.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
str.match(/<b>(.*?)<\/b>/g);
```