# How to append element after particular element in nodejs

Tags: node.js, xml, append

My .XMl is

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<data>
    <shell id="TX-alg1-title">Lesson 2.1</shell>
    <options id="parent">
        <option id="TX-alg1">TX16E_ISE_0005</option>
        <option id="TX-alg1-CID">9780353053</option>
    </options> 
</data>
```

I wanted to add another shell tag after shell tag previously present in xml.

Expected O/p

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<data>
    <shell id="TX-alg1-title">Lesson 2.1</shell>
    <shell id="CA-int1-title">Lesson 2.1</shell>
    <options id="parent">
        <option id="TX-alg1">TX16E_ISE_0005</option>
        <option id="TX-alg1-CID">9780353053</option>
    </options> 
</data>
```

I am reading my .XML file in app.js as

```js
fs.readFile( './dlo_custom_en-US.xml', function(err, data) {
    
});
```

Please advise how to append shell tag after already present shell tag in nodejs.

Answer (score 2):

question is almost similar [Regex match text between tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592033/regex-match-text-between-tags)
node is noting except javascript at server side. almost all programming languages have **regexp** to find patterns. here is simplest solution but you should to study more about **regexp**

```
fs.readFile( './dlo_custom_en-US.xml', function(err, data) {
    data.replace(/\<shell(.)*\<\/shell>/, "new replacement here")
});
```

***** updated *****
from [JavaScript: How can I insert a string at a specific index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313841/javascript-how-can-i-insert-a-string-at-a-specific-index)

```
var fs =require('fs')
String.prototype.splice = function(idx, rem, str) {
    return this.slice(0, idx) + str + this.slice(idx + Math.abs(rem));
};

fs.readFile( './dlo_custom_en-US.xml',"utf8", function(err, data) {
  if(err) return 
   var index  = data.lastIndexOf('</shell>')+8
   console.log(index)
  var data=   data.splice(index,0, 'newwwwwwwwwww')
   console.log(data)
   fs.writeFile('./new.xml',data,(err, done)=>{
    if(err) return 
    console.log(err, done)
   })
});
```

Comment: i dont want to replace as my file has lot of content. I just wanted to append new shell tag after last shell tag found in xml.

Comment: are you sure file have only one </shell> tag or what you want to append after particular  </shell>  tag

Comment: i have 4 to 5 different shell tags in my file, and i wanted to create a new shell tag and append it after the last shell tag i found in xml file.

Comment: is lastIndexof and replace are functions associateed with data in nodejs, as its giving me error as data.lastIndexof is not function

Comment: sorry it it is lastIndexOf pls check again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159797/discussion-between-vishu-and-shivshankar).

Comment: check @Vishu. it's a patch not general purpose solution