# Regular expression to take all the p tag off the string and put it in an array

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string api response that have all sort of data mixed up. What I am looking to do is to write a regular expression to target p tags and take out their content and put them in an array.

Example:

```
const string = "Plain text <p>First para content</p> Another plain text<p>Second para content</p> Another random text and other stuff <p>Third Para content</p>"
```

The desire result can be:

```
const arrayOfParagrahs = ['First para content', 'Second para content', 'Third Para content']
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex match text between tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592033/regex-match-text-between-tags)

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex `/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/g` like in the following snippet:

```js
let str = "Plain text <p>First para content</p> Another plain text<p>Second para content</p> Another random text and other stuff <p>Third Para content</p>"

var result = str.match(/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/g).map(val => {
   return val.replace(/<\/?p>/g, '')
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (without regex) is using regular javascript dom selectors.

You can create a dom element with your html string as innerHTML.

After that you are able to use normal javascript selectors like `getElementsByTagName('p')` or `querySelectorAll('p')`.

```js
const str = "Plain text <p>First para content</p> Another plain text<p>Second para content</p> Another random text and other stuff <p>Third Para content</p>";

const virtEl = document.createElement('div');
virtEl.innerHTML = str;

const pArray = Array.from(virtEl.getElementsByTagName('p'));
const plessArray = pArray.map(e => e.textContent)

console.log(plessArray)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
string.match(/<p>.*?<\/p>/g).map(x=>x.slice(3,-4))
```

```js
const string = "Plain text <p>First para content</p> Another plain text<p>Second para content</p> Another random text and other stuff <p>Third Para content</p>"

let arrayOfParagrahs= string.match(/<p>.*?<\/p>/g).map(x=>x.slice(3,-4))

console.log(arrayOfParagrahs);
```