# Nodejs readFileSync regex tag between two strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, fs, string-matching

I'm trying to fetch file contents with help of `nodejs` `fs.readFileSync()` function into string like this:

```
let fileData = fs.readFileSync('./path, 'utf8');
```

after this I want to get the contents between two string through `regex`:

I've a string something like this:

```
<route-meta>
    {
        "requiresAuth": true
    }
</route-meta>

<template>

</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "check"
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

I need to find text/string between `<route-meta>` and `</route-meta>` so that the result should be:

```
{
   "requiresAuth": true
}
```

I tried doing this with `fileData.match(/<route-meta>(.*?)<\/route-meta>/);` but somehow it is giving me `null` result

I followed through this example: [Regex match text between tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592033/regex-match-text-between-tags)

Also I tried to check `fileData.replace('route-meta', '');` but still it is giving me no desired result I mean I'm unable to do any string operations with `fileData`.

Guide me where I'm doing mistake.

Comment: [Please don't parse HTML with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/1541563).

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Hey Patrick I'm executing `fs.readFileSync()` to fetch the fileData into string, will it still be the issue which you mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't use regex for XML parsing

But to answer your question, you can try this

```
let re = /<route-meta>[\s\S]*?<\/route-meta>/
let re1 = /<(\/*)route-meta>/gi
let newstr = fileData.match(re)[0].replace(re1,"")
console.log(newstr)
```

`re` finds the full set tag with content using `match`
`re1` deletes the opening and closing tag using `replace`