# Regex to pull all data between <pre></pre> tags from a web page

Tags: c#, regex

I have been learning a bit about regex...I am using it successfully in various ways to find links on a website...I have finally gotten to the point where I have a specific page I want to load into a text box...the page is: http://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/0-9/009_sound_system/dreamscape_tab.htm

The song information is contained in `<pre>` tags ... I have tried several regex expressions to try to pull the data from the page between the `<pre>` tags...I am failing.  I don't know if it has something to do with the fact that things in the `<pre>` have carriage returns or line feeds..the first couple of lines in that `<pre>` tag are:

```
Noticed there were no tabs out for this... so I just figured it out in a couple of 
minutes (more like 10). Rather easy. Even mid level beginners ...
```

*Note that the linefeed seems to happen after the words `"couple of"`*

I'm using Visual Studio & C# in a Winforms application (not sure if that matters)

I'm using the following:

```
@"<pre>\s*(.*?)\s*minutes"
```

Using that expression I get the below output:

```
<pre><i></i>Noticed there were no tabs out for this... so I just figured it out in a couple of 
minutes
```

If I try to put anything after the word "minutes" (like "Rather easy.") I get nothing.  I expected that my regex would look something like this:

```
@"<pre>\s*(.*?)\s*</pre>"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks,

ER

Comment: This may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167279/regex-select-all-text-between-tags

Comment: The problem is that the dot doesn't match newlines by default. If you want it does, you must use `regexoptions.singleline` or put `(?s)` at the start of your pattern (or anywhere before the dot).

Comment: Thank you so much...that did it ... my new regex is: @"(?s)<pre><i></i>\s*(.*?)\s*</pre>"  -- I found that using just the <pre> as the starting string gave me 2 matches...if I added <pre><i></i> that gave me only the song part .... Thanks for the quick response.  ER

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte , I'm not sure how to mark your answer as the correct answer.  Is that something I do ...or is that something a moderator does.  Thanks again, ER

Comment: @user2943451: thanks! this is not an answer but a comment. Answers are accepted by authors of questions.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is dont use regex to parse html/xml tags.  Use an xml parser with xpath or something similar

Comment: Agreed..please see comment to George above.

Answer (score 0):

A regex may not be the solution because - Have you considered the fact that there could be embedded  tags within the parent  tags? It gets interesting because of the meaning of  tag. Or is that not a situation?

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation...I saw lots of posts against using regex in this manner to parse HTML ... it's my first time doing HTML parsing and unfortunately my first couple Google searches lead me down that road...I got so close that I really just wanted to get something to work.  My next step will be to investigate what look to be much better solutions for HTML parsing.  Thanks, ER

Comment: Hi user2943451less glad it helped :) Feel free to ask more questions if you get stuck in your research ...

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely go with cpjolicoeur's suggestion of using an xml parser or since it seems that you're in C#, LINQtoXML. For academic reasons, however, I'll offer this

```
/(?<=<pre>).*(?=</pre>)/s
```

or in C#

```
Match match = Regex.Match(yourString, @"(?<=<pre>).*(?=</pre>)",
    RegexOptions.SingleLine);
```

I tested the pattern in [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) which I strongly recommend.

Comment: Thank you for the information.  I will likely abandon the regex stuff and pursue the xml or html parser. ER