# How to use php to find the first letter position which is not part of html tag

Tags: php, string

How to use php to find the first letter position which is not part of html tag. For example the following html string. I want to find the letter 'S' position which is the first letter of Stackoverflow.

```
<p><a href="http://url" target="_blank" >Stackoverflow</a> <a href="http://url" >is</a> usefull for developers.</p>
```

Comment: Google keywords: parse HTML in PHP. You probably don't want to do it in regex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex select all text between tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167279/regex-select-all-text-between-tags)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

Comment: I don't see any mention of regex in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's for HTML rendering then you can use the [CSS ::first-letter Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstletter.asp)

If it's for general string work then I've not found a versatile method yet, but a traditional code implementation (that may be slower) works:

```
function pos_first_letter($haystack) {
  $ret = false;
  if (!empty($haystack)) {
    $l = strlen($haystack);
    $t = false;
    for ($i=0; $i < $l; $i++) {
      if (!$t && ($haystack[$i] == '<') ) $t = true;
      elseif ($t && ($haystack[$i] == '>')) $t = false;
      elseif (!$t && !ctype_space($haystack[$i])) {
        $ret = $i;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return $ret;
}
```

Then call:

```
$i = pos_first_letter( $your_string );
if ($i !== false) {
  $output = substr($s, 0, $i);
  $output .= '<span>' . substr($s, $i, 1) . '</span>';
  $output .= substr($s, $i+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do this with an HTML parser, look at [`DOMDocument::loadHTML`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) or [`DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php). You can then traverse the `DOM` tree to locate a text element. This in turn can be done by traversing the children elements recursively or use [`XPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to locate the desired DOM node.