# Gulp copy HTML and paste to different file

Tags: javascript, gulp

Is is possible using Gulp to copy a portion of HTML (not the entire file) and inject that into a different file?

I have found packages like https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html-replace

and https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject-string

but they can't actually copy HTML.

Comment: How do you identify the portion to be copied ? Is there a container element for the content?

Comment: i would use a RegExp, surrounding the HTML with special comments if needed.

Comment: @11thdimension yes there could be a container or comments

Comment: This seems like an XY problem.

Comment: what do you mean by credible or official source? What could be credible and what could possibly be official?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handling HTML with regular expression is never advised, and there are many arguments ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1356062), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6751339/1356062), [3](http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/)) against that.

The most popular and reliable way to handle an HTML source is by constructing a document model of the source. [JSDOM](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom), is one node.js module that provides a good DOM construction API. Here's a demo of how to solve your case with JSDOM:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var gulp = require("gulp");

var dom = require("jsdom");
var domSerialiser = dom.serializeDocument;

var input = "input.html";
var output = "output.html";

gulp.task("copy-html", function () {
    var extractionPoint = "#extraction-location";
    var insertionPoint = "#insertion-location";

    extractFrom(input, extractionPoint).
            then(insertInto.bind(null, output, insertionPoint)).
            then(saveOutput);
});

function extractFrom(file, section) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        dom.env({
            file: file,
            done: function (error, window) {
                var portion;

                if (error) {
                    reject(error);
                    return;
                }

                portion = window.document.querySelector(section);

                resolve(portion.outerHTML);
            }
        });
    });
}

function insertInto(file, section, portion) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        dom.env({
            file: file,
            done: function (error, window) {
                if (error) {
                    reject(error);
                    return;
                }

                section = window.document.querySelector(section);
                // you may prefer to appendChild() instead, your call
                section.outerHTML = portion;

                resolve(domSerialiser(window.document));
            }
        });
    });
}

function saveOutput(data) {
    fs.writeFile(output, data, function (error) {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        }

        console.log("Copied portion to output successfully.");
    });
}
```

I hope the example above provides a good basis for you to reach a solution specific to your issue.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it using fs and replace, I don't know if it's the best way, but it's works for me.

```
  gulp.task('injectHtml', function() {
    return gulp.src('/dir/file_to_inject.html')
      .pipe(replace('<!-- injecthere -->', function() {
        var htmlContent = fs.readFileSync('/home/file_source.html', 'utf8');
        //regex to get the div content
        return htmlContent.match(/<div id="myDiv">(.*?)<\/div>/)[0];
      }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('/dir'));
  });
```

file_source.html

```
<html>
 <div id="myDiv">test div</div>
</html>
```

file_to_inject.html

```
<html>
 <!-- injecthere -->
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. However, the regexp didnt work for me. This one did it: `/<div id="myDiv">(.|\n)*?<\/div>/`. I need multiline content. Found it in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167279/regex-select-all-text-between-tags#16880892)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I typically use `through2` whenever I want to inject some custom code into the pipe:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var through2 = require('through2');
var fs = require('fs');

gulp.task('default', function(){
  gulp.src('./recipient.html')
    .pipe(through2.obj(function(file, enc, done){
      fs.readFile('./donor.html', function(err, data){
        if(err) throw "Something went horribly wrong.";
        // extract from data the HTML you want to insert
        var contents = file.contents.toString('utf8');
        // insert HTML into `contents`
        file.contents = new Buffer(contents);
        this.push(file)
        done();
      });
    });
});
```

This will pipe the recipient html file through `gulp`, then, read in the donor html file contents. From there you can manipulate both to your heart's content. Then you simply take the result, put it back into the file object, and push that sucker back into the `gulp` pipeline.