# Removing <> tags while reading through log file

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been attempting to use REGEX to display a string between <> tags.  I've looked through several different stackoverflow pages, as well as others, and followed all the tutorials and I cannot achieve what I want.  I want to be able to parse through a log file, match the tags, replace the tags with whitespace, display what was between the tags and not the rest of the file.  I usually end up with the tags being removed, but the rest of the file as well (using replace), or I match the whole statment tags included.

What I've tried:

```
var reg = /(.*<hostname>)(.*)(<\/hostname>.*)/gi;
var match = input.replace("Hostname", " ").match(reg);
```

result: Not a fcn

```
var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig
var match = input.replace(regex, "");
```

refulst: Only takes out the tags and displays rest of file.

```
var regex = /(.*<hostname>)(.*)(<\/hostname>.*)/gi;
var text = inputFile.replace(regex, "$2");
```

result: displays what is between the tags, but also whats in the rest of the file

```
var regex = /(.*<hostname>)(.*)(<\/hostname>.*)/gi;
var text = inputFile.match(regex, "gi");
```

result: displays <> Tags and what I want

In the log file I also have tags with different text in them ... such as   good text , good text , good text etc.  So, I am trying to find how to only match the hostname tags, and display only the text between its tags.
If anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: So if your string is `some text and more text <This text is what I want> but not the rest before or after.` You want to end up with `This text is what I want`?

Comment: Provide a [mcve] and expected results

Comment: Fran ~ Yes.  I know this is probably simple, but I am stuck on this for some unknown reason.  I thought all i had to do was use .match() to find the tags and then use .replace() to remove the tags and only display what was between them, globally through the file. <A Tag> This is what i want </A Tag>

Comment: Charlie - I have edited to describe some of the results I have gotten.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex select all text between tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167279/regex-select-all-text-between-tags)

Comment: Fabio - I do not see how this is a duplicate, similar yes, duplicate i do not believe so.  The main example given in the link is for java.  And by down voting me, it could eventually prohibit me from asking questions, which stops me from getting help and learning.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

Here I am assuming `input` is the stringify data from which you need to eliminate tags

```js
var matchData = $(input).text();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This works well, but it takes away all instances of <> and </> for parts of the file I do not need at that time.  In the log file I also have tags with different text in them ... such as <hostname>  good text </hostname>,<user> good text </user>, <operator>good text </operator>etc.  So, I am trying to find how to only match the hostname tags, and display only the text between its tags.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I was able to get the answer:

```
function regexFind(){

var inputLog = document.getElementById("logFileData").value;
var re = /(<hostname>|hostname\s=\s)(.*)((<\/hostname>|\.).*)/gi;  //var              re= /(<hostname>|hostname\s=\s)(.*)(<\/hostname>.*|\.)/gi;  

var text = inputLog.match(re)//, '$2');\
    console.log(text);

for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  var newText = text[i].replace(re, '$2');
  console.log(newText);
  document.getElementById("newData").value += newText + "\n";
}
```

Comment: ^ Was something I tried earlier, but just didnt have it quite right.  But it works now, thanks for everyones help.