# Regex needed to search for a numeric id within a tag

Tags: regex

My very basic regex skills are not allowing me to successfully extract an id number within a tag.

I think it would be fairly straightforward. I would like to extract the id from the following extract.

```
<id>53222132</id>
```

The id number is not a specific length but I just need to be able to find the id number which is numeric only.

More specifically this is the only instance of the tag *id* so it's unique and should be used within the regex.

Finally is there a way that this can saved within a variable.

Using regex as part of a splunk query where I will use the variable to make it distinct.

I have got as far as the following which captures everything including the tag.

```
<\s*id[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*\/\s*id>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The desired number is in group 1. What language/tool are you using?

Comment: what about this: `(?<=<id>)(.*?)(?=<id>)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex select all text between tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167279/regex-select-all-text-between-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(?<=<id>)\d+(?=<\/id>)`

This would be my first thought.  This will use a positive look ahead and positive look behind and it will only match a string of digit characters in the middle.  Another alternative is:

`\d+(?=<\/id>)`

This will only use the look ahead as the look behind is not entirely supported. One other option:

`\d+(?=\s*<\s*\/\s*id\s*>)`

This will ignore any spaces that might be present in that ending tag, and still find the id regardless.  One of these should work for your scenario.

Comment: `(?<=<\s*id\s*>\s*)\d+(?=\s*<\s*\/\s*id\s*>)` is a combination of all of the above, if you want it to be super specific, but it shouldn't be necessary

Comment: I decided to use the second option proposed here which worked perfectly and was able to capture all the IDs.

Thanks