# How to extract the values for a list of given tags in the xml value using re library?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract the values for a list of data types like string,int,char in a xml file. Apart from these data type tags there are other tags also.

For example there are 2 tags like the below

```
<string> GenIdeal </string> 
 <int>88</int>
```

I've written the below code

```
re.findall(r"<string>(.*?)</string>", elem)
```

and its fetching only string values when tried with

```
re.findall(r"<int|string>(.*?)</int|string>", elem)
```

getting empty values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex select all text between tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167279/regex-select-all-text-between-tags)

Comment: Maybe you want both of values between <string> tag and <int> tag? If so, re.findall(r"<string>(.*?)</string> <int>(\d+)</int>", elem) will return both.

Comment: thanks for your response but either one data type will be there at one point of time and i need to store the value in a variable.

Comment: Use a proper xml parser it will make life much easier and makes extedning your code simpler in the future

Answer (score 1):

To make your regex work just add regular parentheses around the logical alternative, so it will indicate literal:

```py
import re

x="""<string> GenIdeal </string> 
 <int>88</int> """

y=list(re.findall(r"<(int|string)>(.*?)</(int|string)>", x))

print(y)
```

Returns:

```py
[('string', ' GenIdeal ', 'string'), ('int', '88', 'int')]
```

On the side note - if there's more complexity to your use case- consider using XML parser instead e.g.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/xml-parsing-python/

Or

https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/xml/