# get value between html tags and store it to text file

Tags: batch-file

Peace everyone,

am trying to store the vaules between tags to an text file...!
Is this possible using CMD ?

**Examples:**

mybat.bat

```
@echo off
findstr /i "<p>" "file.html" >output_01.txt
findstr /i "<p>.*</p>" "file.html" >output_02.txt
findstr /i "<td>.*</td>" "file.html" >output_03.txt
```

file.html

```
<body>
<p>Try to save me</p>
<p>Try to store me
    If you can :-)</p><table><tr><th>Am Table</th></tr><tr><td>Table 001</td></tr></table>
    <table><tr><th>Am Table</th></tr><tr><td>Table 002</td></tr></table>
</body>
```

output_01.txt

```
<p>Try to save me</p>
<p>Try to store me
```

output_02.txt

```
<p>Try to save me</p>
```

output_03.txt

```
    If you can :-)</p><table><tr><th>Am Table<th/></tr><tr><td>Table 001</td></tr></table>
    <table><tr><th>Am Table<th/></tr><tr><td>Table 002</td></tr></table>
```

**Need output to contains only the value between tags!**

Example:

output.txt

```
Try to save me
Try to store me If you can :-)
Table 001
Table 002
```

Comment: Which tags? There are several sets of tags in your example input but not all of them are used in your example output (like the `<th>` tags and the `<table>` tags).

Comment: yes it's intentionally... case I don't need the others tags...!

Comment: ...you didn't even try to answer my question. _Which tags do we care about?_ Your output doesn't include the `Am Table` value that's between the `<th>` tags so we clearly don't care about all of the tags. Which ones do we ignore?

Comment: Ignore all... except <td> <p>...

Comment: Take a look at this answer with regex [Regex select all text between tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167279/regex-select-all-text-between-tags)

Comment: @Hackoo - I was really hoping you were linking to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @Hackoo am sorry...!

Comment: @Hackoo of course I believe In others languages but what about Batch/CMD?

Comment: @mribraqdbra in batch is not suitable to parse HTML tags ! another thing your HTML example is not valid ! example this tag `<th>Am Table<th/>` should be `<th>Am Table</th>`

Comment: @Hackoo I'm sorry you right...! I just corrected...!

Comment: So this's Impossible?

Comment: @mribraqdbra I think ,you should use a mixture batch with vbscript to reach your aim ! for example if you use this [regex to remove all tags](https://regex101.com/r/tPSMaO/1)

Comment: that's good but I don't know anything about the VBscript...!

Comment: anyway am going to try python...! IS python suitable with this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/639/Removing-HTML-from-the-text-in-ASP)

You can try something like that in batch using regex with vbscript :

```bat
@echo off
Title Remove All HTML Tags using Regex with vbscript
Set "InputFile=input.html"
Set "OutPutFile=output.txt"
Call :RemoveHTML "%InputFile%" "%OutPutFile%"
Start /MAX Notepad "%OutputFile%" & Exit
::--------------------------------------------------------
:RemoveHTML <InputFile> <OutPutFile>
(
    echo WScript.StdOut.WriteLine RemoveHTML(Data^)
    echo Function RemoveHTML(Data^)
    echo Dim strPattern, strReplace, strResult,oRegExp
    echo Data = "%~1" 
    echo Data = WScript.StdIn.ReadAll
    echo strPattern = "<[^>]*>"
    echo strReplace = ""
    echo Set oRegExp = New RegExp
    echo oRegExp.Global = True 
    echo oRegExp.IgnoreCase = True 
    echo oRegExp.Pattern = strPattern
    echo strResult = oRegExp.Replace(Data,strReplace^)
    echo RemoveHTML = strResult
    echo End Function
)>"%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
cscript //nologo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" < "%~1" > "%~2"
If Exist "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" Del "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
Exit /B
::-------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks you a lot...! but the output = 
Try to save me
Try to store me
    If you can :-)Am TableTable 001
    Am TableTable 002

Line break?

Comment: @mribraqdbra This happen because your HTML code isn't well formatted, so, you should write it first correctly to get what you want ! hope that you understand what i mean !