# Convert all <div> to <p> using BBEdit Grep

Tags: replace, grep, tags, bbedit

Using BBEdit Grep, I want to convert all

```
<div>
Text
</div>
```

to

```
<p>
Text
</p>
```

The Text should, of course, remain the same, untouched.

I am using Search `<div>([^>]*)</div>` with Replace `<p>\1</p>`, but this Replace does not work when Text has tags, like `<em>`, or links.

Comment: `<div>([\s\S]*?)</div>`? `<div>((?:(?!</?div>)[\s\S])*?)</div>`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex select all text between tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167279/regex-select-all-text-between-tags)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `<div>([\s\S]*?)</div>` with `<p>\1</p>` works.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find: <(/?)div>

Replace: <\1p>

Comment: It works well, and is simpler than the previous answer. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

This works too:

Search: `<div>([\s\S]*?)</div>`

Replace: `<p>\1</p>`

Comment: Please remove the comment answer and tick the question as a duplicate.