# PowerShell Regex Ignore up until character string match including string match

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to read a file and ignore everything up until a character match. Sometimes the character match will appear on the same line with the results I need, so I can't do a `Select-Object -Skip x` where `x` is the number of lines returned from a document.

I have tried to use the `.Split('<pre>')` method on the results, and that worked, but I can't select the index because it's a multi-line string that returned.

Below is the start of an example of text returning. It's a HTML response that I'm trying to read the data out of. I cannot use the `Content` as it's in ByteArray and has a space between every character. So I've concluded it's time to ask for help with `[Regex]` in PowerShell to assist.

I was looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7124976/1163166) and thought I could use `/.+?(?=abc)/` by means of replacing the search string like this:

```bsh
(Get-Content $env:TEMP\test.txt) | ForEach-Object { 
    [Regex]::Match($_, "^.+(?=\<pre\>)").Value
}
```

That didn't work either. I'm OK with regex when looking for match like `{\d\d\d}` to ensure it's 3 digits long, but I'm not sure how to use it in this instance.

This is the start of a file being returned. I need to ignore everything up to and including the characters `<pre>` and then anything after that to the end of the file is OK.

Example command and result being returned here:

```bsh
PS> Get-Content $env:TEMP\test.txt

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 3524
Date: Thu, 18 Jun 2020 15:00:05 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 19 Jun 2020 01:00:05 GMT
Server: TTWS/1.2 on Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0

<!doctype html><html><body>
    <p>Test TCP WebServer 1.2</p>
    <pre>

    Directory: C:\tmp
```

#### EDIT:

I have this now, which removes everything up to and including the first `<pre>` tag and also removes the closing `</pre>` tag, but won't remove anything AFTER the  closing `</pre>` tag.

```bsh
(Get-Content $env:TEMP\test.txt -Raw) -replace '(?s)^.*?<pre>' -replace '<\/pre>(.+?)'
```

Can that be expanded to include to the end of the file?

Comment: `(Get-Content $env:TEMP\test.txt -Raw) -replace '(?s)^.*?<pre>'` may work for you here.

Comment: try `'(?s)^.*?(?=<pre\s*>)'` matches up until <pre>. if want to ignore and match pre to pre that is differant

Comment: So, essentially, you want the text between the <pre> tags?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167279/regex-select-all-text-between-tags

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Trying to get everything between the two `pre` tags in the HTML

Comment: `Get-Content $input_path -Raw | Select-String -Pattern '(?s)(?<=<pre>\s*).*?(?=\s*<pre>)' -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $output_file`

Comment: I was looking at that solution using Select-String @WiktorStribiżew just as I saw the comment come through. Unfortunately it's not reading it properly. :(

Comment: @AdminOfThings I have made an edit to my post. Are you able to show me how we remove from the `</pre>` tag to the end of the file also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.+?` pattern is "lazy", non-greedy. It means it will match the least amount of characters that it is allowed to match. Since you have `.+?` at the end of the pattern, and `.+?` matches 1 or more characters, it will match **one** character and quit. You need a *greedy quantifier*, `*` or `+`.

Besides, you can achieve what you need with a single `-replace` command if you use a capturing group.

You need to use

```
(Get-Content $env:TEMP\test.txt -Raw) -replace '(?s)^.*?<pre>(.*?)</pre>.*', '$1'
```

It will take the whole file content and get the text contents between the first `<pre>` string and the closest `</pre>`.

**Pattern details**

- `(?s)` - a `RegexOptions.Singleline` inline modifier making `.` match newlines, too
- `^` - start of string
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `<pre>`  - a `<pre>` text
- `(.*?)` - capturing group #1: any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `</pre>`  - a `</pre>` text
- `.*` - any zero or more chars as many as possible (as `*` is a greedy quantifier).

The `$1` in the replacement pattern will restore Group 1 value in the result (so, it will remain).

Comment: Thank you for providing the extra content and giving me a better oversight. I usually only use regex to match what I'm looking for in strings, but that's about it. This really help a lot! Thank you!