# How can I replace text between two HTML tags using regex and PHP?

Tags: php, html, regex

I would like to replace text between two HTML tags and it could contain many HTML tags.

I would like to use `preg.replace()`;

```
<div class="doe"><span>replace text here</span></div>
```

What is the regular expression pattern?

Comment: wouldn't it be better to use a HTML / DOM parsing library?

Comment: Or just use JS innerHTML

Comment: I have to achieve this through php and regex. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex select all text between tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167279/regex-select-all-text-between-tags)

Comment: No. This question has no Pre defined tag rather any html tag.

Comment: you need change example tags for your tags. You want use regex but you probably don't know what is it and how its work. Google more.

Comment: then you can google more about regex

Comment: I'm here because I'm new to regex. I think description is very clear. Would like to change text (string) between html tags opening and ending tags of html.

Comment: _I have to achieve this through php and regex_ Why?

Comment: I'm using wordpress hooks and this is simple for me. Is there a regex pattern for above question.

Comment: I was trying out simple DOM parser php. I was able to select text blocks in the file and by the help of foreach I was able to output all text blocks in the file in array format.

Is there a way to only select specific text block without referring to any html tags or attribute.

After selecting a specific text block, is there a way to replace that specific text block and have it changed on all instances.

Answer (score -1):

If the page is already generated, you won't be able to do this with PHP (PHP is server side).

An easy way to do it is with jQuery.

```
    <script>$(".doe").html('<span>new text</span>');</script>
```

This will update the full content of the div dynamically.

If you want to use data from a PHP page, you can use [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to update the DIV. You just read the PHP page and update the DIV with the data with Ajax (you could just add this to a "onclick" event or whatever)

```
   $.ajax({
       url: "page.php",
       success: function(response) {
           $(".doe").html(response);
       }
```

(This is a pretty basic explanation, because I'm not sure exactly what you want to do.)

Update #1:

According to your comment, you then need this:

```
    $str = '<div class="doe"><span>replace text here</span></div>';
    $regex = '/<div class="doe"><span>(.*?)<\/span>/';
    $replace = '<span>replaced</span>';
    echo preg_replace($regex, $replace, $str);
```

Comment: I'm actually using wordpress hooks, so, I can replace text before page loads.

Comment: then you want that the edit I did in my comment.

Comment: Thanks. The html tags may vary depending upon the code. At one place it could be <H1>replace text here</H1>. At another place it could be <p>replace text here</p>.  This is why I'm seeking regex pattern.

Comment: This is why I'm seeking regex pattern. So that only text between html tags is changed not others like text inside <script> tags.

Comment: @DonbeStup if the text you need to replace is always the same, then probably you can just do a simple string replace, no need for regex. Unless you think the exact same text could occur in other places too in the same page - is that likely? (But if the text to replace is sometimes different, and the HTML tags are also sometimes different, and potentially the text occurs in multiple locations, then the real question is how are you going to actually identify what needs replacing at all? There would be nothing certain to try and detect.)

Comment: Only HTML tags are going to differ. Text that I'm going to change is going to remain same on multiple places in the page. I would like to identify only through text and it must be inside html tags.

Comment: I was trying out simple DOM parser php. I was able to select text blocks in the file and by the help of foreach I was able to output all text blocks in the file in array format.

Is there a way to only select specific text block without referring to any html tags or attribute.

After selecting a specific text block, is there a way to replace that specific text block and have it changed on all instances.