# Replace substring between two substrings

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Please consider the following example:

```
let string = '<h2>Some content here</h2><p>Foo Bar</p><h2>Different content here</h2>'
```

I want to replace what's in between `<h2>` and `</h2>`.

I tried the following approach:

```
string.replace(/<h2.*<\/h2>/, '<h2>xxyyzz</h2>');
```

But the above solutions transforms `string` into:

```
<h2>xxyyzz</h2>
```

Expected result:

```
'<h2>xxyyzz</h2><p>Foo Bar</p><h2>xxyyzz</h2>'
```

How can I replace what's in-between all occurrences of two substrings?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using the DOM API to make these changes? Quantifiers are *greedy* by default, i.e. they match the *longest* substring.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, the algorithm will run serverside, and there is a reason why it cannot be done client side.

Comment: There are also HTML parsers for Node. Just something to consider, depending on how  complex the input really is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the approach will be to adjust your regex:

```
let string = '<h2>Some content here</h2><p>Foo Bar</p><h2>Different content here</h2>';
string = string.replace(/<h2>(.*?)<\/h2>/gm, '<h2>xxyyzz</h2>');
console.log(string); // <h2>xxyyzz</h2><p>Foo Bar</p><h2>xxyyzz</h2>
```

Some details/restrictions:

- tags are case sensitive;
- g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match);
- m modifier: multi line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string);

Similar question:
[Regex select all text between tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167279/regex-select-all-text-between-tags)

Answer (score 1):

```js
let string = '<h2>Some content here</h2><p>Foo Bar</p><h2>Different content here</h2>'
string = string.replace(/<h2>[\s\S]*?<\/h2>/g, '<h2>ABCDEF<\/h2>');
console.log(string);
```

---

Pure javascript alternative

```js
let string = '<h2>Some content here</h2><p>Foo Bar</p><h2>Different content here</h2>'
let tmpele = document.createElement('div');
tmpele.innerHTML = string;

let hs = tmpele.getElementsByTagName('h2');
for(let i = 0;i < hs.length; i++) {
    hs[i].innerHTML = 'ABCDEF'
}
console.log(tmpele.innerHTML);
```

Comment: I'm sure people will find it helpful if you explain what you changed and why you changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex takes all including `Foo bar` part too.

You need to update your regex, eg.

```js
let string = '<h2>Some content here</h2><p>Foo Bar</p><h2>Different content here</h2>';

alert(string.replace(/<h2>[^<]+<\/h2>/g, '<h2>xxyyzz</h2>'));
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioned that this will only work if there is no other tag inside the the heading.