# Regex for python to capture everything between two XML tags

Tags: python, regex, xml

I am trying to capture everything between the "rpc-reply" tags

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rpc-reply message-id="urn:uuid:77a31474-ba9d-4b47-9b4f-60b6497143ed" xmlns:nc="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
 <ok/>
</rpc-reply>
```

Just want to capture "<ok/>" which appears to be a tag itself. So basically I need a regex that will capture anything between <rpc-reply.*> and up to </rpc-reply>
Note this is apart of the ncclient package reply. I tried using their methods to pull the data in the object but they do not work. Also I tried using lxml and beautifulsoup, they also do not work.
I want to just use regex at this point.

Tried the following but nothing seems to work:

```
<rpc-reply.*>(.*)</rpc-reply>
```

Comment: Use xpath statement of `.//rpc-reply/*` to get the node `<ok/>` [Demo](http://xpather.com/PjebxQPH)

Comment: Don't! Don't regex your way around an XML! There are modules meant for parsing XMLs, use them, they're there for good reason.

Comment: Your expression is almost correct. You need to know / special character you should put \ before it.

Comment: You could also replace the (.*) with ([\w\W\s]*).

Comment: Do not use the below suggestion. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58434786/3832970) is the answer, use azy `.*?` with `re.DOTALL` option. Else, use `(?:.*?)` to make a specific dot pattern match across lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you missed scaping the backslash and accounting for eventual multi-lines. The result should look like this:

```
<rpc-reply.*?>((.|\n)*?)<\/rpc-reply>
```

P.S.: One might also look into XML parsing modules (like ElementTree) depending on the use case.

Comment: Never use `(.|\n)*` in regex. This is fraught with catastrophic backtracking.